Keeps me getting tensor object error even when converting
Hi i can' understand where i'm failing with this code, i've tried to fix it many times but still won't work, can anyone help me?
I'm trying to train a neural network in a multilabeling work with BERT's embedding from a dataset and with weights generated by an italian emotion lexicon
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

# Load the emotional lexicon
print("Caricamento del lessico emotivo...")
emotion_lexicon = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Caval\\Desktop\\ELIta_11.04.txt", sep=',', names=['parola', 'emozione', 'valore_float'])

import emoji

# Carica il dataset CSV
print("Caricamento del dataset CSV...")
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Caval\\Desktop\\emit_train_A.csv")

df = df.iloc[:, 1:]

# Divide il dataset in train e test
print("Divisione del dataset in train e test...")
(train_df, test_df) = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Carica il modello BERT pre-addestrato
print("Caricamento del modello BERT...")
bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('dbmdz/bert-base-italian-xxl-uncased')

# Tokenizzazione BERT
print("Tokenizzazione BERT...")
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('dbmdz/bert-base-italian-xxl-uncased', do_lower_case=False)

# Funzione per tokenizzare e convertire in input per BERT
def tokenize_sentences(sentences, tokenizer, max_length):
    print("Tokenizzazione delle frasi...")
    input_ids = []
    attention_masks = []

    for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        print(f"Tokenizzazione frase {i+1}/{len(sentences)}...")
        encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
            sentence,                    # Testo della frase
            add_special_tokens=True,     # Aggiunge token speciali
            max_length=max_length,      # Limita la lunghezza massima
            pad_to_max_length=True,      # Pad fino a max_length
            return_attention_mask=True,  # Genera maschera di attenzione
            truncation=True,             # Tronca gli esempi alla lunghezza massima
            return_tensors='tf',         # Ritorna tensori TensorFlow
        )

        input_ids.append(encoded_dict['input_ids'])
        attention_masks.append(encoded_dict['attention_mask'])

    input_ids = tf.concat(input_ids, axis=0)
    attention_masks = tf.concat(attention_masks, axis=0)

    return input_ids, attention_masks

# Funzione custom tokenizer per integrare le emoji
def custom_tokenizer(text):
    tokens = []
    for char in text:
        if emoji.is_emoji(char):
            tokens.append(char)
        else:
            tokens.extend(tokenizer.tokenize(char))
    return tokens

# Prepara gli input per il train set
print("Preparazione degli input per il train set...")
train_input_ids, train_attention_masks = tokenize_sentences(train_df['text'].apply(custom_tokenizer), tokenizer, max_length=128)

# Prepara gli input per il test set
print("Preparazione degli input per il test set...")
test_input_ids, test_attention_masks = tokenize_sentences(test_df['text'].apply(custom_tokenizer), tokenizer, max_length=128)

# Converti in TensorFlow tensors
print("Conversione in TensorFlow tensors...")
train_input_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_input_ids)
train_attention_masks = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_attention_masks)
test_input_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_input_ids)
test_attention_masks = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_attention_masks)

print(type(train_input_ids))
print(type(test_input_ids))

# Calcola i pesi basati sul lessico emotivo
print("Calcolo dei pesi basati sul lessico emotivo...")
word_weights = np.zeros((len(train_df), 8)) # Inizializza un array per i pesi delle parole
for i, sentence in enumerate(train_df['text']):
  print(f"Elaborazione della frase {i+1}/{len(train_df)}...")
  for word in tokenizer.tokenize(sentence):
    for j, emotion in enumerate(['gioia', 'tristezza', 'rabbia', 'disgusto', 'paura', 'fiducia', 'sorpresa', 'aspettativa', 'amore']):
      # Find all matching words in the lexicon
      matching_words = emotion_lexicon[emotion_lexicon['parola'] == word]
      if len(matching_words) > 0:
        # Iterate through matching words and accumulate weights
        for index, row in matching_words.iterrows():
          word_emotion = row['emozione']
          if emotion == word_emotion:
            word_weight = row['valore_float']
            word_weights[i][j] += word_weight



# Normalizzazione dei pesi per ogni frase (Min-Max Scaling)
print("Normalizzazione dei pesi per ogni frase (Min-Max Scaling)...")
min_values = np.min(word_weights, axis=1, keepdims=True)
max_values = np.max(word_weights, axis=1, keepdims=True)
word_weights = (word_weights - min_values) / (max_values - min_values)

# Converti i pesi in TensorFlow tensor
if word_weights.dtype == np.int:
  print("word_weights contains integers. Converting to float32...")
  word_weights = tf.convert_to_tensor(word_weights.astype(np.float32))  # Convert to float32

# Costruisci il modello
print("Costruzione del modello...")
input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), dtype='int32', name='input_ids')
attention_masks = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), dtype='int32', name='attention_masks')
output = bert_model([input_ids, attention_masks])[0] # Modifica qui
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')(output)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, attention_masks], outputs=output)

# Compila il modello
print("Compilazione del modello...")
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall'])

# Addestra il modello
print("Addestramento del modello...")
model.fit(
  [train_input_ids, train_attention_masks],
  train_df.iloc[:,1:],
  sample_weight=word_weights,
  epochs=5,
  batch_size=16,
  verbose=1
)

# Valuta il modello
print("Valutazione del modello...")
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate([test_input_ids, test_attention_masks], test_df.iloc[:,1:])
print(f'Loss: {loss}, Accuracy: {accuracy}')

# Effettua le predizioni sul dataset di test
print("Predizione sul dataset di test...")
predictions = model.predict([test_input_ids, test_attention_masks])

# Creare un DataFrame per le predizioni
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=test_df.columns[1:])

the traceback that i keep gettint is this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Caval\Desktop\bestia (1).py", line 122, in <module>
    model.fit(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 108, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).

I've tried to convert many times (as u can see in the snippet) in tensor object but still wont work, dont understand why

Have you examined the inputs to fit, [train_input_ids, train_attention_masks],   train_df.iloc[:,1:]?  You may want to convert them to numpy arrays.  My guess is one or more cannot be converted to a numeric array, which is necessary to make a tensor.  There have been many SO about problems making tensors.
